# How to constrcut object array in a container class in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

I have a class `MyData` and a class `Container`

```
classdef MyData < handle
    properties
        x
    end

    methods
        function obj=MyData()
            obj.x=0;
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef Container < handle
    properties
        myobject_array
    end

    methods
        function obj=Container(n)
            obj.myobject_array(n)=MyData();
        end
    end
end
```

When I want to construct a `Container` object by `Container(3)`, the following error is thrown

```
The following error occurred converting from MyData to double:
Conversion to double from MyData is not possible.

Error in Container (line 8)
            obj.myobject_array(n)=MyData();
```

How can I write the constructor of `Container` to make a array of `MyData` object be constructed in `Container` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Container` constructor:

```
classdef Container < handle
    properties
        myobject_array
    end

    methods
        function obj = Container(n)
            MyObjectArray(n,1) = MyData;
            obj.myobject_array = MyObjectArray;
        end
    end
end
```

or:

```
classdef Container < handle
    properties
        myobject_array
    end

    methods
        function obj = Container(n)
            obj.myobject_array = MyData.empty;
            obj.myobject_array(n,1) = MyData();
        end
    end
end
```

---

```
>> c = Container(3);
>> c.myobject_array

ans = 

  3×1 MyData array with properties:

    x
```

Comment: It works, sir, could you please tell me why we can not directly assign on `obj.myobject_array`? It seems that by defalut the `obj.myobject_array` is `double`. Can we told the matlab that the type of `obj.myobject_array` should be `MyData`?

Comment: I believe the answer by @Cris addresses that.

Comment: @XuHui I've also added another possible solution

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to provide a default value for the property:

```matlab
classdef Container < handle
    properties
        myobject_array = MyData;
    end

    methods
        function obj=Container(n)
            obj.myobject_array(n) = MyData;
        end
    end
end
```

(Note that you do not need to provide empty parentheses, `MyData` is the same as `MyData()`. It is traditional in MATLAB to not add the empty parentheses.)